# github increasing the threshould

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to increase the limit.
for that I am querying like this:

curl -iH "User-Agent: Mozilla" https://api.github.com/users/whatever?client_id=26f57d&client_secret=1135ee8

I created a app and kept the id and keys.
I still see that the limit is 60.?
am I missing anything.

2) I am querying the public repos. I see after 60 its giving threshold is met.

Example:
https://api.github.com/repos/webcaetano/mysqldump/contents/ -o contents386

if I run command like this...how can I use the id and secret in the command so that it works.
can we use the access_token? if so how to use in this above command.

Comment: You are better off using tokens as documented here  https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication